# Creating new variable with the difference in days with the previous observation?

Tags: r, datediff

I have a problem calculating the difference in days with the previous observation in a variable and putting that difference in a new variable. The timestamps are stored in a data frame (df) in a variable (date) as year-month-day, like:

```
date
1993-05-05
1993-05-14
1993-06-27
1993-06-27
1993-07-10
1993-07-27
1993-08-23
1993-09-04
```

I would like to create a new variable (`df$days.prev`) with the differences. The intended output should look like:

```
date        day.prev
1993-05-05
1993-05-14  9
1993-06-27  44
1993-06-27  0
1993-07-10  13
1993-07-27  17
1993-08-23  27
1993-09-04  12
```

I tried to do this with

```
df$days.prev <- diff(df$date,lag=1,difference=1)
```

but got an error message:

```
Error in $<-.data.frame (*tmp*, "days.prev", value = c(353, 718, 441,  : 
replacement has 990 rows, data has 991
```

The problem seems obvious to me: for the first observation there is no previous observation, so no difference can be calculated. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: ...use `c()` to just add a 0 or NA at the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
> transform(df, day.prev= c(NA,diff(as.Date(df[,1]))))
          V1 day.prev
1 1993-05-05       NA
2 1993-05-14        9
3 1993-06-27       44
4 1993-06-27        0
5 1993-07-10       13
6 1993-07-27       17
7 1993-08-23       27
8 1993-09-04       12
```

Or

```
df$days.prev <- c(NA,diff(as.Date(df[,1])))
```

Comment: Your solution did not give the desired result, but it point me to the correct approach. With a small change in the code, I got the desired result: `df$days.prev <- c(NA,diff(as.Date(df$date)))`